# Reading 16G from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I have a MongoDB collection that is about 16GB and I'd like to read it into memory all at once and manipulate it.  When reading the data, the code appears to freeze (I've waited 20+ minutes).  I'm running the code from inside a scala play app on a machine with plenty of memory.

I've turned the MongoDB profiler on and when I repeatedly make the following query: `>db.system.profile.find().sort({ts:-1})`
I start by seeing documents containigng the "getmore" operation but then only see my profiler queries (which leads me to believe that all of the records have been read but the function that wraps reading from Mongo hasn't "returned" yet or reading has severely slowed down).  If I run "top" I see that my app is using a ton of the CPU and using all of the memory I've allotted to it (currently 24GB). If I only allocate 8GB to the app, it crashes with a GC error. I should also note that I can run the same code on the same machine just fine if I point it at a smaller DB (2GB). Also, I believe that this collection was originally created using Mongo 1.x and then migrated so that it was compatible with Mongo 2.x (I am not the creator of the collection).

Is my problem related to the size of my data? Is the data itself corrupted? How do I find out?

**EDIT:**
What I'm running is a bit obscured by in house (de)serialization code

```
val initialEntities = for(record<-records) yield {
      /** INSTRUMENTATION **/
      println(...)

      val e = newEntity
      record.fetch(e)
      e}).toSeq
```

`records` is a sequence of everything read from Mongo built from a `CursorIterator` constructed via a `DBCollection.find()` (after importing `com.mongodb`). None of the instrumentation is ever being printed. Fetch uses each record to create an `entity`.

Comment: Show us your relevant code.

Comment: Consider using db repair to make sure db is in a good state but read the doc first: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/.

Comment: You can try to profile your scala app. Check memory consumption with jsconsole. Use iostat, vmstat, free, etc to see where the load is.

Comment: Iterate through everything and throw away results just to check that it's not a memory problem. Don't store docs in a collection just discard them after you read. You might have inefficient query.

Comment: Check mongo logs. Profiler usually writes slow queries there.